# Put two strings into a key and the rest into value from multiple lines in file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

My file has something like this:

```
House Plant, 2, 5, 6
House Plant1, 4, 5, 7
... and so on
```

I want the two words to be as keys and the numbers as integers values and put all of the lines into a dictionary.

```
{'House Plant':[2,5,6],'House Plant1':[4,5,7], etc}
```

And this doesnt really work like that:

```
dictionary = {}

with open("persons.dat","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        items = line.split()
        key, values = items[1], items[2:]
        dictionary.setdefault(key,[]).extend(values)
    print(items)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to split the line based on `,`.

```
items = line.split(',')
```

Also `collections.defaultdict` would be better choice to manage the `list` of items.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dictionary = defaultdict(list)

with open("persons.dat","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        items = line.split(',')
        key, values = items[0], items[1:]
        dictionary[key].extend(list(map(int, values)))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all split your string using `','` :

```
dictionary = {}

with open("persons.dat", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        items = line.split(',')
        dictionary[items[0]] = [int(x) for x in items[1:]]

print(dictionary)
```